# Legacy FCM response now forbidden

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, legacy

Legacy FCM doesn't work anymore since the weekend.

My devices send push notifications via Legacy FCM via fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send. I didn't change anything, but since the weekend I get the error code "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden". Does anybody else have this problem since a few days? 
Changed google something?

I tried my keys with https://www.apnstester.com/fcm/ It still works. So I think google changed something in the firebase console.

Edit:
Is it possible that there is a secured access needed (https) and http is  not supported anymore.

BR, 
Flo

Comment: did you check if you need to enable FCM API for your project at Google API console ?

Comment: Hi Dany. Yes, I checked it. I'm wondering why it doesn't work anymore. I didn't change anything. By chance I noticed it today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem since Saturday. 
I have a node app that send requests to fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send in http and I had a 403 Forbidden on every requests.

Using https fixed the problem.
Apparently the http is not supported anymore. I didn't find any mention of that anywhere though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, meanwhile I've found out, that the problem is http...

I've seen on a Firebase a "last update" date, 13/09/2019 on 2:53, so http is maybe since that time down...